# Excel saved decimal datas as date time

Tags: excel, export-to-excel

After I export my data to Excel my some of my decimal values converted to date format by Excel. For example, my decimal data was 1.25 but it seems Jan.25 in Excel. How can I re-convert to correct decimal format ?

Answer (score 0):

When you import the data set the column data type specifically to `number`.

Without sample data (both input and resulting Excel values) it is hard to diagnose the problem.